# JavaScript задать значение при условии, а в противном случае изменить на другое через секунду (цикл)

Tags: javascript, таймер

Есть цикл, в нём при условиях задаётся значение `innerHTML` элемента.
Необходимо сделать так чтобы при несоответствии условиям (`else`) значение `innerHTML` пустело.

Часть кода (не верного):

```
for (const [i, part] of audio.entries()) {
  const x = (i * bar.width) + ((i + 1) * bar.padding) - (bar.padding / 2)
  const y = 4
  context.fillRect(x, y, bar.width, bar.height * part)
  if (part > 0.575) {
    document.getElementById('ten').innerHTML = 'DANGER!'
  } else {
    if (document.getElementById('ten').innerHTML == 'DANGER!') {
      if (undang != undefined) {
        var undang = setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById('ten').innerHTML = 'not'
        }, 1000);
      }
    } else {
      if (undang != undefined) {
        clearTimeout(undang)
      }
      document.getElementById('ten').innerHTML = i + ' - ' + part
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Пока не понятно, результат всего цикла или просто прохода. Если условие не соответствует `else`, значит оно соответствует `if` и наоборот, если не соответствует `if`, то соответствует `else`. Третьего не дано и надо просто в нужной ветке прописать обнуление. Если надо взять результат всего цикла, заведите булевскую переменную и сохраняйте в ней результат несоответствия, после цикла проверяйте и обнуляйте при необходимости.

Comment: возможно, проблема в `undang != undefined`, попробуйте объявить переменную вне цикла если нужен только последний таймер

Comment: Alex Krass, такой вариант не возможен, так как цикл бесконечный и из него нету выхода.

Answer (score 0):

В теории, он успевают создать таймер и сразу же его убить, думаю вот так должно сработать

```js
var timerEnabled = false;
for (const [i, part] of audio.entries()) {
  const x = (i * bar.width) + ((i + 1) * bar.padding) - (bar.padding / 2)
  const y = 4
  context.fillRect(x, y, bar.width, bar.height * part)
  if (part > 0.575) {
    document.getElementById('ten').innerHTML = 'DANGER!'
  } else {
    if (document.getElementById('ten').innerHTML == 'DANGER!') {
      if (typeof(undang) != "undefined") {
      timerEnabled = true;
        var undang = setTimeout(function() {
        timerEnabled = false;
          document.getElementById('ten').innerHTML = 'not'
        }, 1000);
      }
    } else {
      if (typeof(undang) != "undefined" && !timerEnabled) {
        clearTimeout(undang)
      }
      document.getElementById('ten').innerHTML = i + ' - ' + part
    }
  }
}
```

Проверку делайте вот так, иначе у вас ошибка при проверке, т.к. переменная ещё не объявлена (пусть даже без присвоения).

```
 if(typeof(undang) != "undefined")
```

Comment: Увы, но не помогло. Переменная по прежнему остаётся "DANGER" и таймер не меняет её.

Comment: добавьте перед
    if (document.getElementById('ten').innerHTML == 'DANGER!') 
console.log(11), он туда хоть раз попадает?

Comment: изменил ответ, думаю, что у вас происходит самоубийство таймера, до отработки по таймауту

Comment: Увы, но всё так же...